# Microsoft SQL Server - Limit user access to a single view

Tags: sql, sql-server, permissions

1. I created a user login `[user1]` and map the database `[utils]`
2. In database `[utils]` I created a database role `[CustomViews_ReadOnly]`
3. I added `[user1]` to database role `[CustomViews_ReadOnly]` and to `[db_denydatawriter]`
4. `[CustomViews_ReadOnly]` only has `select` access on a single view `[view1]`

My problem is when `[user1]` connects to the database `[utils]`, he is able to see the list of all tables and other object like views.

How can I limit the user to see the only `[view1]`?

`[user1]` also seems to be able to access other tables and views that are in the `[public]` database role.  How can I limit that as well?

Comment: **Every** user is in the `public` role automatically. If that role has **too many permissions** - you need to remove those from the `public` role.

Comment: Also: while the user might be able to **see** more database objects in e.g. SQL Server Mgmt Studio - can he actually **read** from any of those? Or update any of 'em ??

Comment: @marc_s No cannot read, but I would like to limit the list because user access the database through Tableau software that give him a list of database object.  I would like user only be able to see the single view he has access to.